# Javascript Array Key & Value Selecting

Tags: javascript

So, I'm saving a obj like

```
var user = {"username": username, "info": info};
```

The thing is, this will be saved in an array, if I want to access ONLY that user how would I go about doing that? I'm usering array.push to add it to an array.

Comment: ?? If the object is in an array, like `var a = [user];` then `a[0]` gives you a reference to the object.

Comment: What do you mean "only that user"? If it's in an array, you can get it by the index like this `users[index]`.

Comment: Needs more explanation. You can filter arrays as well; eg. if you only have a username and not the index of that object in the array.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var users = [
  {"username": "Bob", "info": "..."},
  {"username": "Alice", "info": "..."}
];

function getUserByName( name ) {
  var result = users.filter(function (u) {
    return u.username === name;
  });
  return result.length ? result[0] : null;
} 

console.log(getUserByName("Bob"));
console.log(getUserByName("Unkown"));
```

**Note:** The above snippet does not take duplicates usernames in account. It will return the first one it finds.